# How to retrieve record in Hibernate using Unique key instead of Primary Key

Tags: hibernate, key, unique

Using `session.load()` or `session.get()` or any other method of `org.hibernate.session`, is it possible to get a record in hibernate based on the Unique column rather than the PK column value?

My requirement is that I need to get the records based on the unique column value and not the primary key.

It is like I don want to use the Criteria API. I need to use the session.get or load kind of methods. The answer that you have mentioned is for doing a search. But I am asking for getting a single record based on the unique key. Say for eg. My class Fruit has a PK column ID and a unique column fruitID which is unique key. I want to retrieve a unique record based on the fruitID and not ID. eg. Fruit fruit = (Fruit) session.get(Fruit.class,fruitID); here fruitID is the unique column of Fruit class.

Comment: -1 for the lack of information. When asking a question, try posting relevant information about your problem (e.g. code snippets of what you have tried). 
And yes, you can get a collection of records or a record in hibernate w.r.t any column.

Answer (score 8):

You mean something like this?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);  
criteria.add( Restrictions.eqProperty("uniqueField", "value") )
List results = criteria.list();
Object myObj = results.get(0);
```

Check the [hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) for more info about criteria

Comment: Thanks all for the replies!! It is like I don want to use the Criteria API. I need to use the session.get or load kind of methods. The answer that you have mentioned is for doing a search. But I am asking for getting a single record based on the unique key. Say for eg. My class Fruit has a PK column ID and a unique column fruitID which is unique key. I want to retrieve a unique record based on the fruitID and not ID. eg. Fruit fruit = (Fruit) session.get(Fruit.class,fruitID); here fruitID is the unique column of Fruit class.

Comment: any other such methods like get() available in hibernate session?

Comment: Using the Hibernate's Criteria is the easiest way to do this, plus that it is a best practice overall to use criteria. 99% of all handling that you will be needed to do can be done using Criteria. `createCriteria` is a method available in Hibernate's `session` interface, so I really don't see why you do no want to use it.

Comment: you have a typo in the code above: session.list(); should be criteria.list(); - edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this helpful if using a existing table where you need only lookup the row, maybe do simple edits and you do not require the primary key

Move the @Id annotation to the unique key field and leave out the the primary key or make it a normal column

This work if your only doing lookups or editing that table,  issue would arise will more complex operations,  however you could define a second entity just to do the lookup and if you later need to do primary key operations re-lookup by primary key

```
@Entity 
class RealEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(...)
    private String uniqueSecondKey;

    ...
}


@Entity
class LookupEntity implements Serializable {
    @Column()
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(...)
    private String uniqueSecondKey;

    ...
}
```