# Hibernate get Object by non ID , unique identifier

Tags: hibernate, get, uniqueidentifier

I have the following object:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "uniqueId", unique=true)
    private String uniqueId;
```

is it possible to get an object from the DB that has object.uniqueId == "some_unique_id"??

thanks.

Comment: answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258556/how-to-retrieve-record-in-hibernate-using-unique-key-instead-of-primary-key

Answer (score 4):

```
String hql = "select foo from Foo foo where foo.uniqueId = :uniqueId";
return (Foo) session.createQuery(hql)
                    .setString("uniqueId", theUniqueId)
                    .uniqueResult();
```