# how can we give hibernate session.get 2nd arg as non id value

Tags: java, hibernate

Usually I use hibernate session.get(Class.class,**id**) to get entity class.
here in get method I gave 2nd arg as id value (i.e int id=7)
My question is how to use non id value in hibernate session.get(Class.class,**non_id**), I need to get values with some other column (non id column).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate get Object by non ID , unique identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119850/hibernate-get-object-by-non-id-unique-identifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Criteria Queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html). So in your case maybe like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Class.class);  
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("non_id", "myNonIdValue"));
List results = crit.list();
Class myClassObj = (myClassObj) results.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a get with a non-id.  You will have to query for the object you need, like you would in SQL.

```
String queryText = "from SomeObject where objectPropery = :VALUE"
Query queryObj = session.createQuery( queryText );
queryObj.setParameter( "VALUE", value );
return queryObj.uniqueResult()
```

You can read all about queryObjects here: [Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)

If you are querying for objects, you will have to get to know [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html).

Comment: You can't do a `session.get` with a non-id, right. But why buildung a complex query, when Criteria Queries exist? See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hibernate` with `JPA 2`

```
class MyClass { @Id long id; @Basic String description; }

TypedQuery<MyClass> query =
        getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("select myClass from MyClass where description = :description", MyClass.class);
    query.setParameter("description", "example");
   List<MyClass> myClasses = query.getResultList();
```

Or a single entity:

```
MyClass myClass = query.getSingleResult();
```