# could not determine type for <DataType> at table: TableX, for columns org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userPrefs)

Tags: java, hibernate

I searched for this on stack overflow and incorporated the suggestion of putting the annotation over fields or getters but still see the issue so posting.

I have a user table and preference table. Here's the schema

```
create table userpreferences(
ID                              bigint              auto_increment 
user_id                         bigint              not null,
preference_id                   bigint              not null,
preference_value                varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
;

create table user(
  user_id                              bigint              auto_increment,
  user_name                       varchar(255)        not null,
  primary key(user_id)
)
;
```

I want to be able to write a method in my user POJO to retrieve all Preferences for that user. Here's what I have.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends KeyedEntity {

private Long user_id;
private String userName;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs = new HashSet<UserPreferences>();



/**
 * @return Returns the userName.
 */
@Column(name="USER_NAME")
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

/**
 * @param userName The userName to set.
 */
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}



@Id @Column(name="user_id") @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return this.user_id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
    super.setId(id);
}

/**
 * Lazy fetch of the set of application attributes this user has set.
 * @return
 */
public Set<UserPreferences> getUserPrefs(){
    return new HashSet<UserPreferences>(this.userPrefs);
}

/**
 * Setter for the user's attributes.
 * 
 * @param userAttributes
 */
public void setUserPrefs(Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs){
    this.userPrefs.clear();
    this.userPrefs.addAll(userPrefs);
    }

 }
```

Here's my user preference class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userpreferences")
public class UserPreferences extends KeyedEntity implements Externalizable, Cloneable {

private static final int VERSION = 1;

private Long prefId;
private Long userId;
private String prefValue;


@Column(name="PREFERENCE_ID")
public Long getPrefId() {
    return prefId;
}

public void setPrefId(Long prefId) {
    this.prefId = prefId;
}

@Column(name="USER_ID")
public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@Column(name="PREFERENCE_VALUE")
public String getPrefValue() {
    return prefValue;
}

public void setPrefValue(String prefValue) {
    this.prefValue = prefValue;
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeShort(VERSION);
    out.writeObject(this.prefId);
    out.writeObject(this.userId);
    out.writeObject(this.prefValue);
}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    short version = in.readShort();
    if(version>=0){
    this.prefId = in.readLong();
    this.userId = in.readLong();
    this.prefValue =(String) in.readObject();

    }

}

@Id @Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Override
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    super.setId(id);
}


}
```

The error I am getting is this:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(userPrefs)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. I don't know why you have a separate id for `User` and `UserPreference` when `prefId` and `userId` are the primary keys. You should have a `User` type property with name as `user` in `UserPreferences` instead of `Long userId`. That is what `mappedBy="user"` indicate in the `User` class. Also move the annotation to getter. I changed both your classes to make it work. Here is the updated code.

User.java

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    private Long user_id;
    private String userName;
    private Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs;

    /**
     * @return Returns the userName.
     */
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param userName
     *            The userName to set.
     */
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.user_id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.user_id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Lazy fetch of the set of application attributes this user has set.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserPreferences> getUserPrefs() {
        return this.userPrefs;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for the user's attributes.
     * 
     * @param userAttributes
     */
    public void setUserPrefs(Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs) {
        this.userPrefs = userPrefs;
    }

}
```

Preference.java

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "preference")
public class Preference {
    private Long pref_id;
    private String prefName;
    private Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pref_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return pref_id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.pref_id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "PREF_NAME")
    public String getPrefName() {
        return prefName;
    }

    public void setPrefName(String prefName) {
        this.prefName = prefName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "preference")
    public Set<UserPreferences> getUserPrefs() {
        return userPrefs;
    }

    public void setUserPrefs(Set<UserPreferences> userPrefs) {
        this.userPrefs = userPrefs;
    }
}
```

UserPreferences.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "userpreferences")
public class UserPreferences {

    private Long id;
    private User user;
    private Preference preference;
    private String prefValue;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "PREFERENCE_VALUE")
    public String getPrefValue() {
        return prefValue;
    }

    public void setPrefValue(String prefValue) {
        this.prefValue = prefValue;
    }


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="pref_id")
    public Preference getPreference() {
        return preference;
    }

    public void setPreference(Preference preference) {
        this.preference = preference;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.prefValue;
    }

}
```

I removed `writeExternal` and `readExternal` methods for simplicity. And here is the usage in order to get the user preferences.

```
// creating seession factory object
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
// creating session object
Session session = factory.openSession();
// creating transaction object
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

User u1 = new User();
u1.setUserName("Jo");

User u2 = new User();
u2.setUserName("Nick");

Preference p = new Preference();
p.setPrefName("mapping");

UserPreferences up1 = new UserPreferences();
up1.setPreference(p);
up1.setUser(u1);
up1.setPrefValue("ManyToMany");
session.save(up1);

UserPreferences up2 = new UserPreferences();
up2.setPreference(p);
up2.setUser(u2);
up2.setPrefValue("OneToMany");
session.save(up2);

t.commit();// transaction is committed
session.close();

session = factory.openSession();

// creating transaction object
t = session.beginTransaction();

Long u1id = u1.getId();
Long u2id = u2.getId();
System.out.println(u1id + ", " + u2id);
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, u1id);
System.out.println(user.getUserName() + ", " + user.getUserPrefs());
user = (User) session.get(User.class, u2id);
System.out.println(user.getUserName() + ", " + user.getUserPrefs());

t.commit();// transaction is committed
session.close();
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. . will this work without annotating user entity in userPreference without @ManytoOne?

Comment: @AbdullahWasi I don't think so. AFAIK, this is the way to create a one-to-many mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John.
I should have mentioned that I intent to have a separate table named Preferences with ID and name as the columns. The userId and prefId you see in UserPreferences are the foreign keys to the User and Preferences table respectively and are not the primary key in UserPreferences. The ID in UserPreferences is just a auto increment ID which I am treating as primary key(I can avoid using this).

Comment: @Nick01 What would be the relationship between `UserPreference` and `Preference`. IMO, to indicate a foreign key you don't put the primary key of the other class instead a reference to that class. Like I replaced `Long userId` with `User user` and you specify the type of relationship on top of its getter, in this case `ManyToOne`.

Comment: It would be onetomany between Preference and UserPreference I believe since one preference would appear in multiple rows in UserPreferences as part of different users. That means I will need to have a Preference object in the UserPreference class with ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: Yep and a `Set<UserPreference>` in `Preference`. But this whole thing is not making sense to me. What are you trying to do with those `Preferences` and `UserPreferences`. By the naming convention you have I'm guessing that you want to make `UserPreference` a subclass of `Preference`. Paste you whole code and explain what you're trying to achieve. Without proper insight into the problem it is difficult to address it.

Comment: I am giving a shot at designing the thing to store user preferences. A given user would have multiple preferences and I wanted to use hibernate to save it. I came up with a design which has metadata tables for user & preference so a User table would have userId and userName where as preference table would have prefId and prefName. The value table i.e. UserPreferences would have the two Id's i.e. userId and prefId along with a auto increment id and finally a value for the preference. I want to map that into hibernate and this is my first time using hibernate so making north of south :)

Comment: If the relationship between `User` and `Preference` is OneToMany you should actually have only two classes `User` and `Preference`. `Preference` should have `id`, `name`, `value` and `user`. `User` should have `id`, `name` and `preferences`. Just rename the class `UserPreferences` to `Preference` and add `name` field with mapping. It should work. If you want I can change my answer and post the code with relevant table structure.

Comment: No that won't do the job. For one thing, my Preference table would be big since it won't be normalized i.e. id & name combo would repeat X number of times where X is number of users. Also - why do I need preferences in the User table? I am guessing it would be a blob? Or are you suggesting it's not in the  table but in the hibernate object?

Comment: When you say OneToMany, there wont be same preference name (assuming names are unique) that gets repeated for a different user with a different id. I guess what you're trying to achieve is that for the same preference different users have different values. In such case, it is a `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Preference` with relationship having the attribute `value`. That will result in three tables that you're looking for. See this link. http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: "I guess what you're trying to achieve is that for the same preference different users have different values." -- exactly this! I will take a look at the link you provided and would be great if you can give a quick high level design with mappings for this.

Comment: John, how would my schema change with this? Since we no longer have user & pref ID in the user preference table, would I need to store them as blobs? And also, shouldn't getPreference be ManyToMany mapping ?

Comment: With hibernate, instead of holding a foreign key, you hold the whole record which essentially means a reference. The schema would be `User(user_id, user_name), Preference(pref_id, pref_name), UserPreferences(id, user_id, pref_id, preference_value)`. What do you mean storing them as blobs? Are you thinking that every member of a class maps to a column in the database? If so that is wrong. Especially with relationships, it stores the id of the class you're holding. And you can have member variables in a class with the annotation @Transient to indicate that it should not be in the table.

Comment: And for the ManyToMany part, nope. Here we are breaking the ManyToMany between User and Preferences into ManyToOne and OneToMany. If at all you want to use `@ManyToMany` directly, you can have a `Set` representing the other class in each entity and you specify the `@JoinTable` with the table name in this case `userpreferences` but you will not have a `UserPreferences` class. See the example here - http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-annotations-example

Comment: hmm I am getting a error when I save the object.
    could not prepare statement [insert into userpreferences (id, PREF_ID, PREFERENCE_VALUE, USER_ID) values (default, ?, ?, ?)]
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: USERPREFERENCES

Comment: Like it says, check if you have permission. And did you include all the three classes to hibernate configuration file? If you're using the same schema that you posted, you should change the column name to pref_id from preference_id

Comment: Thanks John. I am able to save the UserPreference now but I see that If I save two UserPreference object with each having a new Preference object but same preference name, it creates two entries in the Preference table. How do I make sure it checks if a similar preference exists in the preference table?

Comment: Preference objects are unique based on their `id` not `name`. So you can have more than one preference with the same name. If at all you want to restrict that add the attribute `unique`. Like `@Column(unique=true)getPrefName(){...}`. That way when you try to save a new preference with an existing name, it will throw some exception indicating unique constraint violation.

Comment: You can try to retrieve an existing preference by name and if one doesn't exist you would get null as the response and then you can create it. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258556/how-to-retrieve-record-in-hibernate-using-unique-key-instead-of-primary-key

Comment: also - if I try to create a user object and call the setUserPrefs on it, I expect the UserPreference table to be populated and the Preference table to be populated too in addition to the User table being populated. I don't see that happening in my case.